# Handle expected exception in unit test in MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, mstest

I am testing `DoingSomething()` method with the following test method-

```
[TestMethod()]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException),"Invalid currency.")]
public void ConvertCurrencyTest_ExhangeRate()
{
    try
    {
        DoingSomething();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException Ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

Test result says that `DoingSomething()` did not throw an exception. But it thrown exception indeed.

What did I miss here?

Comment: You are consuming the exception in your try/catch so it is not bubbling up to be caught by the test.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are consuming the exception in your try/catch so it is not bubbling up to be caught by the test.

Remove the `try/catch` and let the test harness handle the exception. Any other exception would naturally cause the test to fail anyway.

```
[TestMethod()]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException),"Invalid currency.")]
public void ConvertCurrencyTest_ExhangeRate() {       
    DoingSomething();        
}
```